# Enable to run appStart task because of NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/jCharts/properties/PieChart2DProperties

Tags: gradle, gretty

I have been successfully able to deploy my web app war file on tomcat using gretty task **appStartWar** or **tomcatStartWar** but when I try to deploy the same web app inplace using **appStart** or **tomcatStart**, I am getting error saying **A child container failed during start, Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jCharts.properties.PieChart2DProperties**.

The gradle configuration for gretty plugin is as follow

```
gretty {
    // supported values:
    // 'jetty7', 'jetty8', 'jetty9', 'jetty93', 'jetty94', 'tomcat7', 'tomcat8'
    servletContainer = 'tomcat8'
    httpPort = 9090
    contextPath = '/portal'
    managedClassReload = true
    fastReload = true
}
```

**Error StackTrace**

```
14:55:05.616 [ERROR] [system.err] SEVERE: A child container failed during start
14:55:05.616 [ERROR] [system.err] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ace2three_portal]]
14:55:05.616 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
14:55:05.616 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
14:55:05.616 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
14:55:05.616 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
14:55:05.616 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
14:55:05.616 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err] Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ace2three_portal]]
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       ... 6 more
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/jCharts/properties/PieChart2DProperties;
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredFields(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1796)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:132)
14:55:05.617 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:336)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:786)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       ... 6 more
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jCharts.properties.PieChart2DProperties
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]       ... 21 more
14:55:05.618 [ERROR] [system.err]
14:55:05.656 [ERROR] [system.err] Sep 05, 2019 2:55:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
14:55:05.656 [ERROR] [system.err] SEVERE: A child container failed during start
14:55:05.656 [ERROR] [system.err] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
14:55:05.656 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
14:55:05.657 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
14:55:05.657 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
14:55:05.657 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
14:55:05.657 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
14:55:05.658 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
14:55:05.658 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
14:55:05.658 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
14:55:05.658 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
14:55:05.658 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:347)
14:55:05.658 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$start$0.call(Unknown Source)
14:55:05.658 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.akhikhl.gretty.TomcatServerManager.startServer(TomcatServerManager.groovy:49)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.akhikhl.gretty.ServerManager$startServer$0.call(Unknown Source)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.run(Runner.groovy:117)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
14:55:05.659 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
14:55:05.662 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
14:55:05.662 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
14:55:05.662 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.akhikhl.gretty.Runner.main(Runner.groovy:44)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err] Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err] Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
14:55:05.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to successfully run tasks **tomcatStart** and **appStart** by using **compile** instead **implementation** in build.gradle